# multiprocessing.Pool graceful termination of child processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to have better control over my pool of processes. I found that calling `break` in the pool loop calls pool.terminate() and forcibly terminates child processes, but I would like to have them finish their chunks and exit gracefully. Manual says I should use pool.close(): `close()
Prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool.`

Test process:

```
chunks = range(7)
with Pool(2) as pool:
    ret = pool.imap_unordered(work, chunks)
    for reply in ret:
        info(reply)
        if reply == "processed 2":
           pool.close()
```

Child process:

```
def work(arg):
    sleep(1)
    return "processed {}".format(arg)
```

I expect at most 2 more tasks to be completed after close() has been called, but nothing is stopped:

```
22:46:00 processed 0
22:46:00 processed 1 
22:46:01 processed 2
22:46:01 processed 3 
22:46:02 processed 4 
22:46:02 processed 5
22:46:03 processed 6
```

Comment: `close` prevents more tasks from being submitted, but you already submitted all your tasks. There's no "unsubmit" option in multiprocessing.Pool.

Comment: @user2357112  is there a way to stop submitting tasks? Should I stop using Pool and handle subprocesses manually?

Comment: I would check out this set of docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes, you can have a shared boolean that can be triggered from a threat which you can test for in your tasks. Definitely cuts down in throughput if you are always checking for termination

Comment: Tank you, @Selecsosi. Performance is not an issue for me as the tasks take ~30 mins each.